# Identifying event bind with specific dom element inside iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to simulate "Download" button click event in this page
https://www.icloud.com/photos/#0i8eO1va2PS_kZp0nKlJ3CG3A

the "Download" button is inside an iframe I try this code in browser console and I get result as undefined

```
 $("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".primary-action span").trigger( "click" )
 $("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".primary-action span").click()
 $("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".primary-action").click()
```

and also when I check the element in devtool it does not show any event bind with the button element.

does anyone how to click the button element inside this iframe ?

Thanks.

Comment: A browser extension doesn't seem to be included, hence if the button is inside a third-party document, you can't. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: but this is same origin.
Isn't it?

page url is https://www.icloud.com/photos/#0i8eO1va2PS_kZp0nKlJ3CG3A

iframe url is https://www.icloud.com/applications/photos3/current/en-us/index.html

Comment: OK, then it should be possible. Notice, that you're mixing jQuery and native DOM properties/methods in your code. `$("iframe")` returns a jQuery object, which doesn't have `contentWindow` property. There should be an error message waiting for you in the console. Use `$( "#iframe" ).contents().find( ".primary-action span" )` to get the reference to the button in the iframe.

Comment: yes that's fine
I get the reference using  document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector(".primary-action")

but there is no event bind with "onclick" event

Comment: any idea how is this possible ? 
no event bind with the element and still this element is clickable and modal is popup

Comment: I've no idea, since I can't see the code (nor the linked pages). Maybe the event is delegated to some ancestor element ..?

Comment: the page is linked in the question 

 https://www.icloud.com/photos/#0i8eO1va2PS_kZp0nKlJ3CG3A

Comment: Yes, but I can't access the pages, a Crash Reporter activates, and the iframe link leads to a 404 page or something alike?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185650/discussion-between-newbie-and-teemu).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try waiting 10 seconds before running those lines? Just to make sure the page is loaded. Im not sure how that page interacts with `window.onload`

Comment: yes.
I ran those lines once page iframe fully loaded
actually selecting event is working perfectly

I mean this part is working perfectly 

    $("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".primary-action")